# Getting segmentation fault on this C programming problem involving structures and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am working on a Hackerrank problem. I am supposed to solve the problem using the given code.

This is the given code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

struct Geometry;

void initRectangle(struct Geometry **object);
void initSquare(struct Geometry **object);
void initCircle(struct Geometry **object);
void initLine(struct Geometry **object);

void printGeometry(struct Geometry* object);

void freeGeometry(struct Geometry* object);

#define SCANF_FMT_CIRCLE    "%f %f %f"
#define SCANF_FMT_RECTANGLE "%f %f %f %f"
#define SCANF_FMT_SQUARE    "%f %f %f"
#define SCANF_FMT_LINE      "%f %f %f %f"


#define PRINTF_FMT_CIRCLE    "Circle with center at %f, %f and radius %f\n"
#define PRINTF_FMT_RECTANGLE "Rectangle with corner at (%f, %f) with width %f and height %f\n"
#define PRINTF_FMT_SQUARE    "Square with corner at (%f, %f) and side %f\n"
#define PRINTF_FMT_LINE      "Line from (%f, %f) to (%f, %f)\n"

int main()
{
  int n;
  struct Geometry **object;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d geometric items\n", n);

  object = malloc(sizeof(struct Geometry*)*n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    char objectType[40];
    scanf("%s", objectType);

    if(!strcmp(objectType, "Rectangle"))
    {
      initRectangle(&object[i]);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(objectType, "Square"))
    {
      initSquare(&object[i]);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(objectType, "Circle"))
    {
      initCircle(&object[i]);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(objectType, "Line"))
    {
      initLine(&object[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Unknown geometric type %s\n", objectType);
      exit(1);
    }

  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printGeometry(object[i]);
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    freeGeometry(object[i]);
  }

  free(object);
}
```

Sample Input:

```
6
Line 0.739 0.053 0.380 0.383
Line 0.098 0.158 0.546 0.531
Square 0.120 0.707 0.346
Rectangle 0.769 0.041 0.995 0.859
Rectangle 0.671 0.520 0.246 0.226
Square 0.333 0.721 0.249
```

Sample Output:

```
6 geometric items
Line from (0.739000, 0.053000) to (0.380000, 0.383000)
Line from (0.098000, 0.158000) to (0.546000, 0.531000)
Square with corner at (0.120000, 0.707000) and side 0.346000
Rectangle with corner at (0.769000, 0.041000) with width 0.995000 and height 0.859000
Rectangle with corner at (0.671000, 0.520000) with width 0.246000 and height 0.226000
Square with corner at (0.333000, 0.721000) and side 0.249000
```

I need to write the functions.

What I tried:

I wrote a struct, with some bool variables to indicate which geometry item is under consideration:

```
struct Geometry
{
    bool isrectangle, isquare, isline, iscircle;
    float x1, x2, y1, y2;
    float square_corner1, square_corner2, side;
    float center1, center2, radius;
    float rectangle_corner1, rectangle_corner2, width, height;
};
```

Next, to initialise the struct, I am reading input like this, inside the function definition, using `scanf`.

```
void initRectangle(struct Geometry **object){
    scanf(SCANF_FMT_RECTANGLE, &((*object)->rectangle_corner1), &((*object)->rectangle_corner2), &((*object)->width), &((*object)->height));
    (*object)->isrectangle = true;
    (*object)->iscircle = false;
    (*object)->isquare = false;
    (*object)->isline = false;
}
```

Similarly, other init functions are completed. Other 2 functions are completed like this:

```
void printGeometry(struct Geometry* object){
    if (object->iscircle == true){
        printf(PRINTF_FMT_CIRCLE, object->center1, object->center2, object->radius);
    }
    else if (object->isline == true){
        printf(PRINTF_FMT_LINE, object->x1, object->x2, object->y1, object->y2);
    }
    else if (object->isquare == true){
        printf(PRINTF_FMT_SQUARE, object->square_corner1, object->square_corner2, object->side);
    }
    else {
        printf(PRINTF_FMT_RECTANGLE, object->rectangle_corner1, object->rectangle_corner2, object->width, object->height);
    }
}

void freeGeometry(struct Geometry* object){
    free(object);
    object = NULL;
}
```

I got segmentation fault with this message:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f3d6afb481f in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, 
    format=format@entry=0x402004 "%f %f %f %f", 
    argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fff2d49d5f0, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:2445
```

Based on the seg fault error message, I think my mistake has to do with the reading input to the struct. Why am I getting a segmentation fault? What is the right approach for this problem?

Comment: It looks like the argument passed to  the function`initfunction` is invalid. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Your `scanf()` line works well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MmRFqWgnpW4Zq1fs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be malloc'ing each of the `Geometry *`'s within `object`. Otherwise, the pointers you are passing to `initRectangle` are essentially garbage values, and therefore dereferencing them will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Each element within your `Geometry **` array should be malloced, you would probably want something like `malloc(sizeof(Geometry *)`. As it currently is, you are only allocating space for the entire array of pointers, but each of those pointers must also be allocated individually. Does this help at all?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you. I did `object[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Geometry *));` in the for loop